# Limit the number of views in a web part

Tags: development

Is it possible to select which views of a document library that should be available in a web part displaying the document library? This seems to partially solve the problem:

http://watsburning.blogspot.com/2011/07/dynamically-changing-views-of.html

However, I want end users to be able to select which views to be available in the web part themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop down in the article that you've provide - that is filled with hard coded view names - user selects a view and it's shown in the webpart. So I suppose the webpart fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the code provided above does not allow end users to choose available views for the web part themselves. I chose to inherit System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.EditorPart to enable that.

Comment: I suppose it should provide, not sure about your implementation. There is a DropDownList with ID="DropDownViews", there you should hard code (in advanced version you can get them) view names, on page_load selected view is received from the dropdown.